# GCP Authentication for Python with LOADED JSON , NOT file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

To Authenticate pipeline in Python project I'm using this

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "path/to/the/json/key.json"
```

How to do the same thing BUT with the loaded JSON file? (without using path to the JSON)??

Comment: The environment variable is processed by the SDKs. There are no environment variable method to use the JSON body instead of the file name. You will need to use one of the library **from_service_account_info()** methods to load raw JSON.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have just checked the link in the provided solution and found exactly what you have mentioned.... have not tried it yet... but looks like this should solve the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to authenticate against a project in Google Cloud.
Please take a look at: https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html as well as the best practices as mentioned here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/best-practices-applications